# how to use variable substitudes as array names

Tags: bash

suppose I have 2 arrays:

```
A=(a1 a2 a3)
B=(b1 b2 b3)
```

I want to display contents of A and B with a loop, something like this:

```
for i in A B
do
    echo ${${i}[@]}
done
```

and get results like this

```
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
```

how can I realize this?

Answer (score 2):

Use indirect parameter expansion.

```
for i in A B; do
  t="$i[@]"   # A[@] or B[@]
  echo "${!t}"
done
```

The trick is to treat the array name plus the index (`[@]`) together as a variable "name".